# Context setStatus() not working in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

`context.setStatus(..)` does not print when i am running my map reduce job.

This is part of my reducer code:

```
@Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
    context.setStatus("Constructing image");
            try {
                image = new BufferedImage(context.getConfiguration().getInt("image.size", -1),
                        context.getConfiguration().getInt("image.size", -1), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just setting the status will not print anything to stdout. It will however show in the web UI.

If you want to print the status to stdout you can add the line

```
System.out.println(context.getStatus());
```

or

```
logger.info(context.getStatus());
```

if you are using some logging framework.